# Does Jodd framework provide mechanism to inject petitebeans references for objects created by other frameworks

Tags: jodd

Does Jodd framework provide mechanism to inject petitebeans references for the objects created by other frameworks.

Below are scenarios
- Domain/Service objects are created by Spring Framework
- Domain objects created are by ORM Frameworks
- These objects need to be injected with Repository/DAO object (Singleton objects registered as PetiteBean via AutomagicPetiteConfigurator)

---

Below is sample code, after petite container is shutdown, initMethod() is invoked when pc.getBean(Greetings.class).message(null) is invoked and destroyMethod() is not invoked, can you please point me what I am doing wrong?

```
@PetiteBean("greetings")
public class EnglishGreetings implements Greetings {

    @Override
    public String message(String message) {

        if (message == null) {
            return "defaultMessage";
        }
        return message;
    }

    @PetiteInitMethod
    public void initMethod() {
        System.out.println("Entered initMethod");
    }

    @PetiteDestroyMethod
    public void destroyMethod() {
        System.out.println("Entered destroyMethod");
    }
}

public class GreetingRunner {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingRunner.class);

    @PetiteInject
    public Greetings greetings;

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        jodd.log.LoggerFactory.setLoggerFactory(new Slf4jLoggerFactory());

        PetiteContainer pc = new PetiteContainer();
        AutomagicPetiteConfigurator configurator = new AutomagicPetiteConfigurator();
        configurator.setIncludedEntries("com.rans.*");
        configurator.configure(pc);
        pc.shutdown();
        System.out.println(pc.getBean(Greetings.class).message(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `pc.shutdown();` _before_ using `getBean`?

Comment: @игор, Intent to call pc.shutdown() was to check the following  - Whether destroyMethod() will be invoked marked with PetiteDestroyMethod annotation  and Beans cannot be accessed after Petite Container is shutdown

Comment: please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy method has not been invoked because of *lazy* aspect of Petite - if bean has not been used, no destroy method will be called. The same applies to init methods. If bean is not used, Petite simple ignores it.

Now back to the question:

> Does Jodd framework provide mechanism to inject petitebeans references for the objects created by other frameworks.

Technically, yes - if you overwrite it :) See `PetiteProxettaContainer`. You may override `getBean` and use 3rd party container to fetch the bean. Actually, you may override `createBeanDefinitionForRegistration` method to register the bean in the different container. To be honest, we might make this more obvious :)

(Sorry for late response)

Comment: After PetiteContainer shutdown() method is called, can PetiteContainer be configured to throw exception when trying to access beans via PetiteContainer getBean APIs

Comment: Hey @NRV, in 3.7.1 we will delete all the bean data. Would that work you - instead of throwing exception?

Comment: And feel free @NRV to mark the question answered, for other ppl